# ArchLinux BSPWM

Tags: arch-linux, bspwm

I just installed archlinux using the archinstall script, and I selected bspwm as my desktop. It finished and my screen is blank with just the cursor showing. What would be the next step towards making it usable and maybe looking like exodiaos

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Follow this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLBm0C5Gv58 and this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lLa4IoVdCo&t=491s When i first installed arch with bswpm i had blank screen also. Good luck